# SED (or other find and replace); altering embedded tags

Tags: xml, regex, replace, sed, findandmodify

I have many instances following this format in .xml file:

```
<FFFFF>
    <BBBBB>
         "good B data"
    </BBBBB>
    <BBBBB>
         "more good B data"
    </BBBBB>
</FFFFF>


<AAAAA>
    <BBBBB>
         "some data"
    </BBBBB>
    <BBBBB>
         "more B data"
    </BBBBB>
</AAAAA>
```

I am trying to remove the A tags, and rename the B tags that are in the A tags; so the final result would be: (please note, renaming the B tags to any tags would also be fine, they just cannot be B anymore)

```
<FFFFF>
    <BBBBB>
         "good B data"
    </BBBBB>
    <BBBBB>
         "more good B data"
    </BBBBB>
</FFFFF>

 <AAAAA>
      "some data"
 </AAAAA>
 <AAAAA>
      "more B data"
 </AAAAA>
```

I have been messing around with sed, but I cannot figure out how to do it. There is no set number of B tags in each A (some have none, some may have 20, etc.). The other issue is that I don't want to remove the B tags that are present elsewhere; so I cant do a simple find and replace on B tags as that would alter the ones embedded in .

Any assistance appreciated, thanks!

Comment: For this you might actually want to use an xml parser (it looks like xml, anyway) with Python/Ruby/etc. I don't think sed per se can handle this.

Comment: Yeah it is xml; is there one you recommend?

Comment: If you use Python, [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) seems to be the most popular. I can't think of any for Ruby off the top of my head, but searching for "ruby xml" should get you a bunch of matches. (Edit: Nokogiri is a popular parser for Ruby.)

Comment: Use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) and python instead of trying to regex this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
<FFFFF>
    <BBBBB>
         "good B data"
    </BBBBB>
    <BBBBB>
         "more good B data"
    </BBBBB>
</FFFFF>


<AAAAA>
    <BBBBB>
         "some data"
    </BBBBB>
    <BBBBB>
         "more B data"
    </BBBBB>
</AAAAA>

$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ remove="AAAAA"; changeFrom="BBBBB"; changeTo="XXXXX" }

$1 ~ "^<" remove ">$" {
    inRemove = 1
    next
}

inRemove {
    if ($1 ~ "^</" remove ">$") {
        inRemove = 0
        next
    }
    else if ($1 ~ "^</?" changeFrom ">$") {
        sub(changeFrom,changeTo)
    }
    sub(/^    /,"")
}

{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
<FFFFF>
    <BBBBB>
         "good B data"
    </BBBBB>
    <BBBBB>
         "more good B data"
    </BBBBB>
</FFFFF>


<XXXXX>
     "some data"
</XXXXX>
<XXXXX>
     "more B data"
</XXXXX>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^<AAAAA>/,/^<\/AAAAA>/ {
   /^<\/*AAAAA>/ s/^<\/*AAAAA>//
   /^<\/*AAAAA>/ !{
      s/^\([[:space:]]*\)<\(\/*\)BBBBB>/\1<\2AAAAA>/
      }
   }' YourFile
```

1. This is for your sample so maybe it could be usefull to use a variable for the TAG to search/modify
2. Space in front of modified tag (indent) is unchanged
3. Line containing old  are just empty but still there